# The problem of distortion on the composite

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, tracking

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hi all, I have a problem. I will render an object, is simply a box, get the rendering, compositing, then distort it. As a result of rendering over a live video the cube is smaller and renders with a curvature. What do I need to do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

I add more pictures with my problem. I know how to do it in other programs, but I want to learn how to do in a blender. Help me.

[image]

Comment: can you upload the video and the blend file?

Comment: Why not simply undistort the Footage?